# is it possible to use conditional import and part-of with Dart?

Tags: dart

I have this base class that should be generic used through the VM, Flutter and Web:

```dart
// base.dart
abstract class Foo {
  void _method();
}

void doMethod(Foo foo) {
  foo._method(); 
}
```

Here are the io and web version:

```dart
// web.dart 
import 'dart:html' as html;

class Bar implements Foo {
  void _method() => html.someMethod();
}

// io.dart
import 'dart:io' as io;

class Bar implements Foo {
  void _method() => io.someMethod();
}
```

I wouldn't like to expose `_method` outside the package.

Is this possible with conditional imports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Conditional imports (and exports) are only allowed on imports and exports.
A part declaration cannot be conditional.

What you can do is to let the implementation of `_method` come from a top-level function:

```dart
import "src/default.dart" 
  if (dart.library.io) "src/io.dart"
  if (dart.library.html) "src/web.dart"
  as impl;

class Foo {
  factory Foo() = impl.Bar;
  void _method() => impl.fooMethod(this);
}
```

and then, e.g., `src/io.dart` can be:

```dart
import "../foo.dart";
class Bar extends Foo {
  void _barMethod() => io.something;
}
void fooMethod(Foo foo) => (foo as Bar)._barMethod();
```

That way you can abstract the implementation of the private method into a separate library.